# Get Response body from response object in Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a middleware to Log all the request and response(for API). But response is not showing in the terminate method response object.

```
class Logger
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        Log::info('ApiLog done===========================');
        Log::info('URL: ' . $request->fullUrl());
        Log::info('Method: ' . $request->getMethod());
        Log::info('IP Address: ' . $request->getClientIp());
        Log::info("Data: ",[$request->all()]);
        // Log::info("Query String: ", [$request->query()]);
        Log::info("Response".$response->getContent());
    }
}
```

But $response->getContent() returns null.
First i try using handle only with process the request and get the response then Log it using

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    Log::response("",[$response])

    return $response;
}
```

But the object doesnot contain body. It only has the status and header information.
Can you help me please to get the response body

Comment: I tried terminate on my project now and it printed out the whole body as you are using it. Do you have the middleware registered in `app/Http/Kernel.php` as a route or global middleware?

Comment: It is registered as a middlewareGroup

Comment: then in routes using that middleware for a group of routes

Answer (score 2):

this is a `print_r` of the HttpResponse from debugging:

```
Illuminate\Http\Response Object
(
    [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
        (
            [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                    [no-cache] => 1
                    [private] => 1
                )

            [cookies:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [headerNames:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                    [date] => Date
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                )

            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => no-cache, private
                        )

                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Thu, 04 Oct 2018 14:17:16 GMT
                        )

                    [content-type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                        )

                )

            [cacheControl:protected] => Array
                   (
                )

        )

    [content:protected] => foobar content
    [version:protected] => 1.1
    [statusCode:protected] => 200
    [statusText:protected] => OK
    [charset:protected] => 
    [original] => foobar content
    [exception] => 
)
```

The property `content:protected` is replaced by "foobar content" because of its big size. You can call `$response->setContent('foobar content');` to set the contents value or `$response->getContent();` to receive the content value.

If `$response->getContent();` returns null, then you have to check the object type of $response. Maybe its not `\Illuminate\Http\Response`.

This is my test middleware:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        /** @var Illuminate\Http\Response $response */
        $response = $next($request);
        $foo = $response->getContent();

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I will respond here to share bigger code instead of commenting. So based on the documentation it should be either in the `$routeMiddleware` or `$middleware` because if you open the framework `Kernel` you will see this:

```
$middlewares = $this->app->shouldSkipMiddleware() ? [] : array_merge(
        $this->gatherRouteMiddleware($request),
        $this->middleware
    );
```

on those the `terminate` function is called.

Comment: I have tried putting it in $routeMiddleware / $middleware also. Still no response body showing. Logged both response and getContent() method on response object both has empty body

Comment: ResponseHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:          Thu, 04 Oct 2018 13:48:10 GMT
Set-Cookie:    laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik9MT3RFWWFwd0dQZXQwQXJ3anFyb0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRHg0RVdXdzlVTWZ3b2p3Y0tuS3JCWUNKbEM2OVJaSlBRS2xPRmlRUk45NU93bUdhRFBjcGtVVWN6SVoyemlzdTdYa29iMmU1MzBGUFRsa3hZaFFHa0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijg5NDlhYmYxNzc2NDU4ZjA1ZGI3MGU5MTQ0NmMyNWI3MDI1MjBlZDgxZTBlNDNjMzNiMjYwNWRlM2U1MWFhNDgifQ%3D%3D; expires=Thu, 04-Oct-2018 15:48:10 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly

Comment: This is response object and $response->getContent() shows nothing

Comment: both tested in handle and terminate method

Comment: Can you please share what to you return from your controller action?

Comment: $responseData = array('success'=>'1', 'data'=>array(), 'message'=>"Device is registered.");
  $userResponse = json_encode($responseData);
  print $userResponse;

Comment: Response i get  in browser :{"success":"1","product_data":[{"products_id":21,"products_quantity":9999,"products_model":"Polo","products_image":"resources\/assets\/images\/product_images\/1502193410.pPOLO2-19116009_standard_v400.jp.................

Comment: try returning the response, not just printing it.. 

so `return $userResponse` should be the line in your controller.

Comment: Thank you that is the issue

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer it will give me some reputation :)